# Neo4j Cypher to C# how to create different relationships with other nodes based on the value of a parameter

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create something like this:

```
Match (rt:Root{Name:root})
Match (o:Organization{orgName:"Org1"}) 
create (u:User{FirstName:"User1", UserRole:"is_member"}) 
CASE  
When u.UserRole="is_member" Then Create (u) -[:"is_member"] -> (o) 
ELSE u.UserRole="is_guest" Then Create (u) -[:"is_guest"] -> (o)
ELSE u.UserRole="is_admin" Then Create (u) -[:"is_admin"] -> (rt)
```

So depending on UserRole, different relationships will be created between the user and other nodes. For some reason, this is not working in Neo4j and also what would be the equivalent in C#

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several syntax errors.

The following query should work (note: I opted to use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE` to avoid creating duplicates in case you repeat the same query):

```
MATCH (rt:Root{Name:root}), (o:Organization{orgName:"Org1"})
MERGE (u:User{FirstName:"User1", UserRole:"is_member"})
WITH rt, o, u,
  CASE u.UserRole
    WHEN "is_member" THEN {m: [1]}
    WHEN "is_guest"  THEN {g: [1]}
    WHEN "is_admin"  THEN {a: [1]}
  END AS todo
FOREACH(x IN todo.m | MERGE (u) -[:is_member]-> (o) )
FOREACH(x IN todo.g | MERGE (u) -[:is_guest]->  (o) )
FOREACH(x IN todo.a | MERGE (u) -[:is_admin]->  (rt) )
```

A [CASE](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/expressions/#query-syntax-case) expression can only generate variables -- it cannot do operations like  `CREATE` or `MERGE`. Although the above query also contains a `CASE` clause, it just generates a `todo` variable whose value is either an object or `NULL` (if none of the `WHEN` tests are satisfied).

Unlike a `CASE` expression, a [FOREACH](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/foreach/) clause *can* perform `CREATE` or `MERGE` operations. So, the above query has 3 of them -- but *at most one* of them will actually perform a `MERGE`, since a `FOREACH(x IN todo.foo | ...)` clause does nothing unless `todo.foo` exists and is a non-empty list. (We don't need to use the `x` variables, so they are ignored.)

*Also: The APOC procedure [apoc.do.case](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_case_procedures) was recently added, and theoretically could be used instead of the above `CASE` and `FOREACH` approach.*

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! I am trying to translate that in C#. What would be the equivalent of the CASE clause?